# Connecting a Wi-Fi repeater to a captive portal Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-extender

I just moved in a student residence, and internet is provided by Wifirst. It's an open Wi-Fi but I have to connect through a portal each month. I use Arduinos for my studies and a Google Chromecast, so I need a private Wi-Fi connection to make it work.

I wanted to know if it was possible to plug in an external router in order to create a private Wi-Fi network where I can connect all my devices.

I have two RJ45 Ethernet sockets in the room and thought of the TP Link Nano Router to connect them.

Do you know if it will be possible for me to connect it, although there is a captive portal? And if so, how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

> I have two RJ45 Ethernet sockets in the room and thought of the TP
> Link Nano Router to connect them.
>
> Do you know if it will be possible for me to connect it, although
> there is a captive portal? And if so, how to configure it?

You need to ask the school tech support about connecting a router to the RJ45 connection.

It should be straightforward to connect.

Connect an Ethernet cable from the RJ45 socket in the room to the WAN port on your own router.

Configure the WAN port to connect. This is where school tech support comes in. They will give you the connection parameters.

Now configure the LAN side of your router to a normal inside address. Likely it is 192.168.1.1 or close to that

Now you have your private network for your devices.

This should work.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this week and get back to you!